# Empty statement in Matlab switch/case?

Tags: matlab, switch-statement

I was reading [this](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/f363f3abf9e55cb117fdbdcdfe44b95ec838ca5f/toolbox/sift/vl_phow.m) code and at line 97 I found the following code:

```
switch lower(opts.color)
  case 'rgb'
  case 'opponent'
  ...
```

I've never seen empty statements (according to [documentation](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html)). What does it mean?

"If `lower(opts.color)` is either `rgb` or `opponent` then do `...`"

or

"If `lower(opts.color)` is `rgb` do nothing and if it's `opponent` do `...`"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the `case` block is empty, then nothing is executed for that particular case. So if `opt.colors` is `'rgb'` no action is taken.

The reason that the author has even bothered to include it as a `case` is because if they hadn't, the code within the `otherwise` block (which sets `opts.color` to `'hsv'` because the supplied colorspace wasn't recognized/valid) would be executed if `opt.colors` was `'rgb'` which obviously is undesirable behavior.

The block is the functional equivalent of

```
if ~strcmpi(opts.color, 'rgb')
    switch lower(opts.color)
        case 'opponent'
            % Do stuff
        case 'hsv'
            % Do other stuff
        otherwise
            % Throw warning
    end
end
```

The syntax for a `case` block which matches several values requires the use of a [cell array for the case expression](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html#bucqfa5-2).

```
switch lower(opts.color)
    case {'rgb', 'opponent'}
        ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! :)